# Calculate Picture ID for Gallery With Ads

Tags: javascript, algorithm, refactoring, formula, image-gallery

I have a picture gallery where after every three pictures, an ad is displayed (gotta pay those bills ).

So in an example scenario, my gallery would have 11 slides, of which there are 9 pictures and 2 ads, like this:

[image: gallery]

In the top row of this drawing are the zero-based indexes of the slides, which I have in an array.

What I need to come up with now is a formula to calculate the index of the picture corresponding to a given slide ID (the numbers in the bottom row).

So for `slideIndex === 2`, I need `picIndex === 2`, for `slideIndex === 5`, I need `picIndex === 4` and for `slideIndex === 8`, the result would be `picIndex === 6`.

For a slide that contains an ad, I would like to have the index of the last pic, so for `slideIndex === 3` → `picIndex === 2`.

I do have a working solution already, where I just use a `for` loop, but this seems really lame and cumbersome:

```js
const adInterval = 3; // show an ad every 3 pics

function calculatePicIndex(slideIndex) {
    let picCount = 0;
    let picIndex = -1;
    for (let i = 0; i <= slideIndex; i++) {
        if (++picCount > adInterval) {
            picCount = 0;
        } else {
            picIndex++;
        }
    }
    return picIndex;
}

for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    console.log(`slide index: ${i} – pic index: ${calculatePicIndex(i)}`);
}
```

I'm sure there is a much more elegant solution with a simple math formula, so basically, it's more a math question than a JavaScript question:

**How can I refactor the above code to avoid the loop and calculate the number through a math formula?**

I have tried something like this:

```
const picIndex = slideIndex - Math.floor(slideIndex / adInterval);
```

But that gives me incorrect values which are more and more off as slide index increases.

See JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pahund/1bobtkyp/3/

Comment: your ad interval need to be 4 and not 3 thats your mistake, your formula is correct

Comment: Thanks! Not quite, though, by adding 1 to adInterval, I get the correct picIndex values for slides that have a pic in them, but for ad slides, I get the index of the pic in the next slide, while I need the index of the pic in the previous slide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is almost correct, you only have to add 1 to the slide index and ad interval to fix it:

```js
const adInterval = 3;

for (let slideIndex = 0; slideIndex < 12; slideIndex++){
    let picIndex = slideIndex - Math.floor((slideIndex + 1) / (adInterval + 1)); 
    console.log(`slide index: ${slideIndex} – pic index: ${picIndex}`);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've corrected your code a bit so that it gives the correct pic index for slides that have an ad on them.